# How to verify availability of a room between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about an hotel room reservation system, those are my tables:

[image]
I would like to find available rooms with this sql request in php:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('
SELECT * 
  FROM chambres c
  LEFT 
  JOIN booking b
    ON c.numero_chambre = b.no_chambre 
 WHERE b.no_chambre IS NULL 
    OR (b.check_out <= :check_in AND b.check_in <= :check_out)
    OR (b.check_out <= :check_in AND b.check_out >= :check_out)');
$stmt->bindParam(':check_in',$date_in);
$stmt->bindParam(':check_out',$date_out);
$stmt->execute(); 
$resultats= $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($resultats);
```

I think the condition is working, but for exemple, if i want to find available room between '2021-01-15' and '2021-01-22', it still finds that the room 1 is available because
it can see in my booking table, the row :

[id] => 1 [hotel_id] => 1 [numero_chambre] => 1 [check_in] => 2021-01-13 [check_out] => 2021-01-15 [no_chambre] => 1 [date_creation] => 2021-01-11 [client_id] => 1 )

Does someone would have an idea to resolve this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN by ranges overlapping condition and return the rows without matching.

Comment: The test for overlaps is as follows: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. There's no 'OR' in this sentence.